# php echo iframe escape characters

Tags: php, iframe, escaping

I am having trouble finding the correct syntax for escape characters and echoing or printing an iframe output in PHP.

```
 $youtube = $_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'];
    if($_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'] == '')
    {
         print "<div class=\"someClass\">Some Text Here</div>";
    }
    else
    {
         print "<iframe id="player" width="425" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$youtube" frameborder="0"></iframe>";
    }
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction or provide me with a useful link for explaining escape characters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes using backslashes, or you can use single quotes as well.

In your version, the `if` block is absolutely fine. Similar to that you need to correct the `else` block as well by escaping double quotes `\"` like shown here,

```
$youtube = $_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'];
if($_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'] == '') {
     print "<div class=\"someClass\">Some Text Here</div>";
}
else {
     print "<iframe id=\"player\" width=\"425\" height=\"350\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$youtube\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
}
```

Using single quotes:

```
$youtube = $_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'];
if($_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'] == '') {
     print '<div class="someClass">Some Text Here</div>';
}
else {
     print '<iframe id="player" width="425" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$youtube" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape all the double quotes (") with a backslash (\). This should work:

```
$youtube = $_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'];
if($_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'] == '') {
    print "<div class=\"someClass\">Some Text Here</div>";
} else {
    print "<iframe id=\"player\" width=\"425\" height=\"350\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$youtube\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
}
```

Or you can wrap the statement in single quotes instead like this:

```
$youtube = $_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'];
    if($_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'] == '') {
        print "<div class=\"someClass\">Some Text Here</div>";
    } else {
        print '<iframe id="player" width="425" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$youtube" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use If statement or use Echo statement or Print those will also work!!

Ex.

```
if($_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'] == '' ) {

print "//here your code ";

} else {

print "//your code";
}
```

OR

```
if($_SESSION['SESS_YOUTUBE'] == '' ) {

echo "//here your code ";

} else {

echo "//your code";
}
```